# numactl and move_pages mismatch

Tags: linux, openmp, numa, numactl

I have developed a simple program to test in which NUMA node a page is, based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986903/can-i-get-the-numa-node-from-a-pointer-address-in-c-on-linux/8015480#8015480).

The problem is that comparing my program results with `numactl -H` on a Xeon E5-2698 v4 (two NUMA nodes) shows different outputs. `numactl -H` shows(cropped):

```
available: 2 nodes (0-1)
node 0 cpus: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59
node 1 cpus: 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79
```

So, for example, `numactl` says that cpu 20 is at node 1. I have the following code:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <numaif.h>
#include <omp.h>

int numa_node(void *ptr) {
  int status;
  int ret_code;
  if((ret_code = move_pages(0, 1, &ptr, NULL, &status, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("move_pages");
    return -1;
  }
  return status;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int pgsize = getpagesize();
  printf("NUMA test(pgsize=%d)\n",pgsize);
  #pragma omp parallel firstprivate(pgsize)
  {
    if(omp_get_thread_num() == 20) {
      char *m = aligned_alloc(pgsize, pgsize);
      m[0] = 'a';
      if(mlock(m, 10) == -1) {
        perror("mlock");
      }
      else {
        int node = numa_node(m);
        printf("thread %d: node %d\n",20,node);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using `aligned_alloc` trying to allocate just a page, aligned, so that
when this thread "touches" this page, it will be mapped to the NUMA node where this thread is (first touch policy). Then I use `mlock`, which you can check in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19813681/numa-how-to-check-in-which-part-of-ram-a-c-array-is-allocated?noredirect=1&lq=1). I suppose I'm using first touch since I modified nothing related to this, however, I don't know how to check this, to make sure.

I'm compiling this with `icc -fopenmp -lnuma`and running with `KMP_AFFINITY=granularity=fine,compact`,`OMP_NUM_THREADS=80` and 
`numactl -m 0,1 ./numa`. I'm ussing this affinity since I think it does the same assignation as numactl sees the system. This outputs:

```
NUMA test(pgsize=4096)
thread 20: node 0
```

So, this program says thread 20 is at node 0 but `numactl` says thread 20 is at node 1. Why? I was expecting to see the same output on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requested affinity setting `compact` will place consecutive threads to neighboring hardware threads (Hyperthreading) on the same core. The numbering of the OS cpus numbers the additional hardware threads later, so cpu 0 and 40 are on the same core. The mapping will be as follows:

```
tid -> cpu
0 -> 0
1 -> 40
2 -> 1
3 -> 41
...
20 -> 10
```

You can see that by adding `,verbose` to `KMP_AFFINITY`. If you want a direct mapping, you can use `GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY=0-79` instead of the `KMP_AFFINITY` settings. That should do the trick to get the memory on the right NUMA node.